# PySpark: How to filter out rows before a specific condition

Tags: pyspark

How can I remove all rows before a certain condition in PySpark?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([
            ['A', '2019-01-01', None, None, None],
            ['A', '2019-01-02', None, None, None],
            ['A', '2019-01-03', 'O', 'O', 1],
            ['A', '2019-01-04', 'O', 'P', 2],
            ['A', '2019-01-05', 'O', 'P', 3],
            ['A', '2019-01-06', None, None, None],
            ['A', '2019-01-07', None, None, 4],
            ]),
                           ['ID', 'Time', 'State', 'State2', 'LatestRecord'])
```

```
# expected
+---+----------+-----+------+------------+
| ID|      Time|State|State2|LatestRecord|
+---+----------+-----+------+------------+
|  A|2019-01-03|    O|     O|           1|
|  A|2019-01-04|    O|     P|           2|
|  A|2019-01-05|    O|     P|           3|
|  A|2019-01-06| null|  null|        null|
|  A|2019-01-07| null|  null|           4|
+---+----------+-----+------+------------+
```

The condition that jumped out to me was to say, remove all rows where `Time` is less than `LatestRecord == 1` but I am quite stuck as to how to make that happen.

My (failed) attempts so far:

```
# transform min date; fails
df = df.withColumn('earliestDate', F.when( F.col('LatestRecord') == 1, F.col('Time').over(Window.partitionBy('ID'))))

# then when earliestDate >= Time, filter
df = df.filter(df.earliestDate >= df.Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Devised an answer as follows that seems to work / can filter on:

```
# condition that I can filter by
w = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy(F.asc('Time'))
criteria = F.when((F.col("LatestRecord") == 1), F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))
df.withColumn("Flag", F.when(F.sum(criteria).over(w) > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))).show()
```

```
+---+----------+-----+------+------------+----+
| ID|      Time|State|State2|LatestRecord|Flag|
+---+----------+-----+------+------------+----+
|  A|2019-01-01| null|  null|        null|   0|
|  A|2019-01-02| null|  null|        null|   0|
|  A|2019-01-03|    O|     O|           1|   1|
|  A|2019-01-04|    O|     P|           2|   1|
|  A|2019-01-05|    O|     P|           3|   1|
|  A|2019-01-06| null|  null|        null|   1|
|  A|2019-01-07| null|  null|           4|   1|
+---+----------+-----+------+------------+----+
```